# Search API Solr integration with fivestar (or similar) rating system (fascet and sort)

Tags: rating, search

I'm attempting to sort nodes by ratings using the Search API faceted search with Solr integration. I've already set up fivestar ratings (about 9 per node, its a large multi-axis rating system.) but i'm unable to index these ratings!

Can someone help me understand how to change this so I can use a facet search for ratings?

Otherwise, are there any recommendations on other modules (aside from fivestar) which would allow the votes to be indexed?

Thank you!

Justin

Comment: Just a shout-out for Apache Solr Search Integration, with its own API: http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr and Apache Solr Views: http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_views and last but not least, this issue in the queue on Voting API project: http://drupal.org/node/387050

Answer (score 3):

You can best create a new Entity property in a `hook_entity_property_info_alter()`, and add a custom field "rating" with a custom getter callback. Like so:

```
...
      $properties = &$info['flatrow']['properties'];
      $properties['my_indexable_rating_axis_1'] = array(
        'type' => 'integer',
        'label' => t('Rating axis 1'),
        'query callback' => 'entity_metadata_table_query',
        'getter callback' => 'rating_axis_one_get_properties',
      );
      return $properties;
...
```

Use it to extend the node entity. The getter callback is where you retrieve the value to be indexed,

```
function rating_axis_one_get_properties($entity, array $options, $name, $entity_type) {
  $value = $node->field_fivestar['average_rating']; // I made this up, check how to do it

  return $value;
}
```

Then index the field with Search API.